# Позиционирование плиткой картинок без пробелов

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, изображения, css, php

Доброго времени суток, уважаемый Хэшкод и его участники! У меня возникла новая задача, заказчик поставил задачу реализовать такую штуку. Мне интересно есть ли алгоритмы такие, специальные, которые позволяют правильно позиционировать картинки плиткой, прижимая их к друг другу, чтобы при загрузке новых картинок все пересчитывалось и формировалось опять? Или это надо самому придумывать как это делать? Я не говорю еще и про css+hmtl правильную разметку, чтобы при масштабе и изменениях размера браузера все отображалось корректно. Просто кто как понимает, каким способом можно такого достичь? Картинку приложил к вопросу... [картинка](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/c3f08fd60b49/example.jpg)

Уточнил у заказчика что именно надо, он сказал надо сделать примерно как в сервисе гугл картинки, то есть плиткой уложены они и прижаты к друг другу, размеры кардинально не отличаются, тоесть нет прямоугольных картинок или очень узких по высоте или ширине, все примерно равны, хотя отличия есть все же:

Как вот такое реализовать можно, алгоритмы (библиотеки) есть готовые такие на php, чтобы позиционировать картинки правильно? Или все самому надо изобретать тут велосипедное?

[image]

Comment: покажите как раскладывать, если картинок  5 и все они с разным соотношением сторон, причем есть как portarait так и landscape

Comment: @eicto, мне вот это тоже не понятно как можно уложить в плитку такую картинки с разным соотношением сторон, наверное исходится из того, что пропорции все же примерно схожие. Это желание заказчика, мне остается только думать над тем как решить эту задачу. Судя по картинке, пропорции примерно схожие у всех.

Comment: приверно схожих пропорций не бывает.в общем уточните у его дизайнеров эти вопросы, тут же дело в чем - может просто так получиться, что не выйдет разложить без искажения пропорций, поэтому надо брать крайние случаи и по одному примеру тут не решить 

единственную похожесть я вижу - все картинки landscape или квадрат, выясните есть ли portrait

Comment: @eicto, спасибо за ответ, ладно буду спрашивать у дизайнеров эти вопросы... задача не из простых конечно.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu

Comment: @IntegralAL
на самом деле мне кажется, что решение есть только для каких-то частных случаев наборов картинок, т.е. возьмите нарисуйте несколько наборов самостоятельно попробуйте их собрать вручную, все что не получится отправьте дизайнерам и пусть они скажут как такие "исключения" обрабатывать. например - 4 квадрата и один прямоугольник, в квадрат

Comment: Наткнулся на такую интересную статью: http://habrahabr.ru/post/135421/  может кому покажется полезной, правда там исходников нет, но идея изложена в статье вся.

Comment: Вообще на картинке изображен явный inline block но не просто картинок, а с оборачивающим дивом выравнивающим по высоте строки

Answer (score 1):

А почему не javascript, а именно php? В гугле полно плагинов к jQuery, ближайшие по смыслу -- галереи (есть еще слайдеры и карусели, но это немного не то).

Comment: можно и js. Это может даже предпочтительнее будет, я пытался искать подходящий плагин на JQuery тоже, но не нашел такого именно рода сортировку картинок.

Comment: Я не возьму в толк при чем тут JS или PHP ведь задача сводится к правильной верстке. Оберните каждую картинку в див фиксированной высоты, и просто вывалите их подряд с display: inline-block

Comment: @donkey потому что надо картинки в "правильном" порядке расставить. вот что  вы предлагаете http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/T5n2n/